# Adding priority to jQuery

Tags: jquery

My code looks like:

```
'click #foo': function(e, t) {
    $('#otherId').click();

    //further instructions
}
```

At this moment, 'further instructions' are made, and then 'otherId' is clicked.
I need to click 'otherId' first of all, before #foo will make other instructions.
I know that click() is working asynchronous but I am not able to work this out.
Is there any (simple) way to add priority to $('otherId').click(); instruction?

Comment: what are further instructions?

Comment: In further instructions I need to add post to database. But before I do, I need to click #otherId first.

Comment: _add post to database_ Are you doing it async?

Comment: Well, I am calling methods in meteor in further instructions, which are adding post to database. And then, even if $('#otherId').click() is on the very begining of the code, post is added to database (method is executed), and then otherId is clicked.

Comment: see event you have put the click on top of everything but functions and variables have the highest priorities so if you are calling a function then that will execute before the click event.

Comment: I see, but is there any simple way to force this instructions to click button (otherId), right before making other instructions?

Comment: i can suggest you to put the further instructions in a function and call those function at last of the other instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what framework do you are using, but you can try this:

```
'click #foo': function(e, t) {
    $('#otherId').click();
 },
 'click #otherId': function() {
      // further instructions
 }
```

When you trigger the click, then listen it and make the other instructions

Comment: don't you think question to ask should be "what are further instructions?"

Comment: The problem is that #otherId is hidden. User is not able to click it himself. It needs to be clicked at first, after clicking #foo.

Comment: @ArcadioMorales but in this example user haven't to click himself to the element, you are making in click #foo an automatic trigger.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. But #otherId has other instructions than 'further instructions'. I need #foo to do stuff, but before it does, it should click #otherId button which is hidden and it has its own instructions.

Comment: Tell us what are these instructions, because if you are making an asynchronous call it's radically different to a normal instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this

```
'click #foo': function(e, t) {
    $('#otherId').click(function(){
        //further instructions
    });
    $('#otherId').trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of callbacks:

```
function furtherInst(){
    // further instructions
}
```

now in your event bindings:

```
'click #foo': function(e, t) {
    $('#otherId').click();
},
'click #otherId': function() {
  // other instructions

  furtherInst(); // call it here at the end

}
```